# Reading PointCloud2 in C++

Tags: c++, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you read a PointCloud2 in C++? I'm interested in getting the depth(z point). Maybe an equivalent of this: [reading pointcloud2 in python](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4440).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9239/reading-pointcloud2-in-c++/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you know what type of points you expect inside the PointCloud2, you can use the information from the pcl_ros wiki page for [Subscribing to point clouds](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros#Subscribing_to_point_clouds).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-03-03**:
For some reason, I did not notice that. Thanks.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-03**:
Note that that is an optical frame, with Z pointing along the camera's viewing axis, not a standard body frame. In that situation, the camera frame should be specified with an _optical suffix, as noted in REP 105: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#coordinate-frame-conventions .

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-03**:
That warning isn't a big deal. The question I had was what sort of reference frame the PointCloud was using. According to the diagram and docs at http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc#stereo_image_proc.2BAC8-common.Nodes , /camera ought to be the frame of the left camera in the pair.

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-03-03**:
The frame_id is [camera]. I actually have a warning message on the rviz console window saying [camera] is not a fully qualified frame_id (resolved locally to [/camera]). I have not setup any tf here.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-03**:
What is the reported frame_id in the PointCloud2 you are reading?

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-03-03**:
I'm just using the pointcloud from stereo_image_proc. Where is the origin here? (top-left corner? top-right corner? center of the image?)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-03-02**:
That depends on whoever sends the pointcloud and what frame the data is in. For sensors the origin is usually (0,0,0). A negative y is also not unexpected. It could mean a point right or below the sensor (depending on the coordinate system)

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-03-02**:
Is the origin(0.0, 0.0) of points x and y at the center of frame? I'm seeing a negative y point here.

**Comment by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on 2018-07-19**:
@Eric I did not understand your solution. Can you elaborate? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You seem already got an accepted answer but just for future reference,

You could use     `convertPointCloud2ToPointCloud`  from sensor_msgs.

Once you input Pointcloud2 and  got output as Pointcloud , then you can iterate through your points as such;

```
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/point_cloud_conversion.h>
    
sensor_msgs::Pointcloud2 input_pointcloud;
sensor_msgs::Pointcloud out_pointcloud;
sensor_msgs::convertPointCloud2ToPointCloud(input_pointcloud, out_cloud);
            
for(int i = 0 ; i < out_cloud.points.size(); ++i){
    geometry_msgs::Point32 point;
            
    //Dooo something here
    point.z = out_cloud.points[i].z;
}
```

And get xyz coordinates of all points

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3